# RabbitMQ: Can vhost span multiple physical nodes in a Rabbit cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq

As the question reads, I would like to know if it is feasible to create a vhost for redundancy, replication, and high availability on multiple nodes in a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vhost is always created on all *nodes* in a RabbitMQ *cluster*.

Now if you want your vhost to be in multiple *clusters* you'd have to add the vhost via `rabbitmqctl` or the HTTP API.